# Cross compilation of cmake on Linux under Windows with QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, cross-compiling

I want to cross-compile a cmake project for Linux under Windows. The project uses QTBase. What have I done:
downloaded source code of QTBase from [official repository](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/). Further compiled with i686-mingw.
In cmake (I cite below). I include the recommended mingw file that overrides the paths to the compiler (I cite it below).
The application compiles successfully, but wine reports the lack of some libraries (also below). In Windows, this compiled application also does not work, citing the lack of libraries.
How to describe cmake correctly?

```
# the name of the target operating system
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

# Choose an appropriate compiler prefix

# for classical mingw32
# see http://www.mingw.org/
#set(COMPILER_PREFIX "i586-mingw32msvc")

# for 32 or 64 bits mingw-w64
# see http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/
set(COMPILER_PREFIX "i686-w64-mingw32")
#set(COMPILER_PREFIX "x86_64-w64-mingw32")

# which compilers to use for C and C++
find_program(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-windres)
#SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-windres)
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-gcc)
#SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-gcc)
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-g++)
#SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-g++)


# here is the target environment located
SET(USER_ROOT_PATH /home/erk/erk-win32-dev)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/${COMPILER_PREFIX} ${USER_ROOT_PATH})

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

CMake project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
include(../Toolchain-cross-mingw32-linux.cmake)
project(naiveTextEditor LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/dym/CLionProjects/QTShared)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
        resources.qrc)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Core> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Gui> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Widgets> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>
        )
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
```

Wine output:

```
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libwinpthread-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Core.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\naiveTextEditor.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libwinpthread-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Core.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Gui.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\naiveTextEditor.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libwinpthread-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Core.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Widgets.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libwinpthread-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Core.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Gui.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Widgets.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Widgets.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\Qt5Widgets.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Widgets.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\naiveTextEditor.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\naiveTextEditor.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\naiveTextEditor.exe") not found
0009:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\dym\\CLionProjects\\naiveTextEditor\\bin\\naiveTextEditor.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

My notes:
It seems that the linker paths are written so that the application looks for all dlls in its folder.
Can I specify to look for system dlls in system folders?

Comment: In CMake a [toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling) is specified via `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable, not via `include` command.

Comment: BTW, on Stack Overflow bad questions are fixed by **editing** them, not by deleting the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646531/cross-compilation-of-cmake-on-linux-under-windows-with-qt) and asking a new one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but there was also an incorrect design